# Moving some certain folders in a directory into a folder in the same directory in bash scripting linux

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

i wanted to move some folders in a directory into the another folder in the same directory. I want three of the folders in the directory to stay there and all the others into one of these three folders.

```
for folders in */; do
    if ["$folders" != "constant"] || ["$folders" != "system"] || ["$folders" != "postProcessing"]; then
        mv folders ./postProcessing
    fi
done
```

I get this error:

```
line 10: [0/: No such file or directory
line 10: [0/: No such file or directory
line 10: [0/: No such file or directory
line 10: [0.1/: No such file or directory
line 10: [0.1/: No such file or directory
line 10: [0.1/: No such file or directory
line 10: [0.2/: No such file or directory
line 10: [0.2/: No such file or directory
line 10: [0.2/: No such file or directory
```

I'd really appreciate if somebody can help me out.

Best Regards

Comment: Put a valid shebang and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendations.

Comment: On a side note, folder and directory are the same, so please clarify what is the difference between the two...

Comment: `shopt -s extglob; mv !(constant|system|postProcessing)/ postProcessing`